# SVG sprite as list-style-image is possible?

Tags: css, svg, pseudo-class

I can use SVG images as list-style-image with:

```
ul { list-style-image: url('my.svg'); }
```

But what if I have an SVG sprite, and I want to use it for the list image? 
Is that possible?

I had thought about using `::before` pseudo element, but I wonder if there is a more "natural" way to achieve that

Comment: Why you think using pseudo element isn't *natural*?

Comment: Maybe the term "natural" is not the best choice :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#accessibility_concerns

There are accessibility concerns to `list-style: none`

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making between an SVG image and an SVG sprite. Does the sprite truly have multiple images in it you intend to show only a portion? It would be helpful to describe how `ul { list-style-image: url('my.svg'); }` fails to do what you want.

Comment: `list-style-image` is actually the right answer. See related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347084/positioning-a-svg-icon-as-list-style-image or an example here https://www.mediaevent.de/css/list-style-image.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SVG Fragment Identifiers](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/).

Here is the SVG that I use in the example. The two circles have an id and they are only visible if they are the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      circle {
        display: none;
      }
      circle:target {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <circle id="c1" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
  <circle id="c2" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="steelblue" />
</svg>
```

And here the example, where the URL of the SVG is replaced with a data URI. You can see the `#c1` and `#c2` in the end of the long data URI. But it works the same as `list-style-image: url('my.svg#c1')` and `list-style-image: url('my.svg#c2')`.

```css
ul.orange {
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8ZGVmcz4KICAgIDxzdHlsZT4KICAgICAgY2lyY2xlIHsKICAgICAgICBkaXNwbGF5OiBub25lOwogICAgICB9CiAgICAgIGNpcmNsZTp0YXJnZXQgewogICAgICAgIGRpc3BsYXk6IGlubGluZTsKICAgICAgfQogICAgPC9zdHlsZT4KICA8L2RlZnM+CiAgPGNpcmNsZSBpZD0iYzEiIHI9IjUwIiBjeD0iNTAiIGN5PSI1MCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgaWQ9ImMyIiByPSI1MCIgY3g9IjUwIiBjeT0iNTAiIGZpbGw9InN0ZWVsYmx1ZSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+#c1');
}

ul.steelblue {
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8ZGVmcz4KICAgIDxzdHlsZT4KICAgICAgY2lyY2xlIHsKICAgICAgICBkaXNwbGF5OiBub25lOwogICAgICB9CiAgICAgIGNpcmNsZTp0YXJnZXQgewogICAgICAgIGRpc3BsYXk6IGlubGluZTsKICAgICAgfQogICAgPC9zdHlsZT4KICA8L2RlZnM+CiAgPGNpcmNsZSBpZD0iYzEiIHI9IjUwIiBjeD0iNTAiIGN5PSI1MCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgaWQ9ImMyIiByPSI1MCIgY3g9IjUwIiBjeT0iNTAiIGZpbGw9InN0ZWVsYmx1ZSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+#c2');
}
```

```html
<ul class="orange">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="steelblue">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```